# The method "nextLine()" is undefined for the type String

Tags: java

I'm making a program with multiple different methods, one of them being:

```
private static void IsWordPattern(String input) {

    String pattern = "";
    System.out.println("Enter a pattern of letters: ");
    pattern = input.nextLine();

}
```

I get the error, "The method "nextLine()" is undefined for the type String"

However, the scanner is clearly defined at the top of my class,

```
public class StringValidation {

static Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
```

I am able to use the scanner in my main function without error:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    String userInput = input.nextLine();
```

As well as I am able to use it in ANOTHER method that is also private and static:

private static int Menu(int choice) {

```
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    while(choice < 1 || choice > 9) {

        System.out.println("Select an option from the menu below: "
                + "\n1. Letters only"
                + "\n2. Numbers only"
                + "\n3. Binary data"
                + "\n4. Hexadecimal data"
                + "\n5. Binary data which represents an even number"
                + "\n6. A binary string which contains one of 2 patterns"
                + "\n7. Validate a binary stirng which contains both of the patterns"
                + "\n8. Determine if a word is a pattern"
                + "\n9. Exit");


        if(choice < 1 || choice > 9) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input -- try again\n");
        }

    }
    return choice;
}
```

I tried multiple methods of fixing whatever this error is, including changing the Menu function definition to "private static void Menu" and that didn't work either. Why am I getting this error, and what can I do to solve this. Any and all feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You're reusing the variable name `input`. So the method `IsWordPattern` can't see the `Scanner` variable, it only sees the `String` variable. Which doesn't have the `nextLine` method. Just change the name of your `String` input argument.

Answer (score 3):

Your method parameter is shadowing your class field which has the same name. You can either change the parameter name or call the class field with `this.` e.g.

```
 pattern = this.input.nextLine();
```

Note: To access static class variables you would use the class name instead of `this` keyword in this case it would be `StringValidation.input.nextLine()`

Comment: Note: The variable is static

Comment: @cricket_007 noted

Answer (score 2):

The scanner variable in the class is shadowed by the String parameter called `input`. You should rename the function parameter, then the scanner is visible again.